# “LinkConnect::linkc: -- Message text not found” on startup, removing ~/.Mathematica helps

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

We have a university license of Mathematica. In `/usr/remote/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.3/Configuration/Licensing/mathpass` on all the Debian 9 systems we have the content:

```
!wolframlicense.physik.uni-bonn.de
```

One user experiences that Mathematica cannot be started, instead the following output is emitted on the console:

```
$ mathematica
$

LinkConnect::linkc: -- Message text not found -- (LinkObject[8u2xs_shm, 3, 1])
LinkConnect::linkc: -- Message text not found -- (LinkObject[s88jc_shm, 3, 1])
```

She told me that deleting `~/.Mathematica` fixes the issue. It seems to be caused by improperly logging off or having Mathematica crash. I did not experience that with my user account.

From what I found online it seems that this `LinkConnect` is used by remote kernels and also the licensing server communication. Since it is coupled to files in the home directory, it might be some stale socket to the university's license server?

---

A `.Mathematica` directory that caused the problem contains these files:

```
.Mathematica.bak/
|-- ApplicationData
|   |-- CloudObject
|   |   `-- Authentication
|   `-- Parallel
|       `-- Preferences
|           `-- Preferences.m
|-- Applications
|-- Autoload
|   `-- PacletManager
|       `-- Configuration
|           `-- FrontEnd
|               `-- init_10.3.0.0.m
|-- FrontEnd
|   |-- 10.3_Caches
|   |   `-- Linux-x86-64
|   |       |-- FileMenuCache.pbf
|   |       |-- ResourceMap.pbf
|   |       `-- SystemFiles
|   |           |-- CharacterEncodings
|   |           |   `-- UTF-8.pbf
|   |           `-- FrontEnd
|   |               `-- TextResources
|   |                   `-- UnicodeCharacters.pbf
|   `-- init.m
|-- Kernel
|   `-- init.m
|-- Licensing
|-- Paclets
|   |-- Configuration
|   |   |-- managerData_10.3.0.0.pmd2
|   |   |-- pacletData_10.3.0.0_7885263109545408621.pmd2
|   |   `-- pacletSiteData_10.pmd2
|   |-- Repository
|   `-- Temporary
|       `-- QuantityUnits-1.2.1.19262308.paclet
|-- SystemFiles
|   |-- CharacterEncodings
|   |-- FrontEnd
|   |   |-- Palettes
|   |   |-- StyleSheets
|   |   `-- SystemResources
|   |       `-- FunctionalFrequency
|   |           `-- CodeAssistHistory10.3.m
|   |-- Kernel
|   `-- SpellingDictionaries
`-- term.history
```

And this is what changes against a freshly created `.Mathematica` directory:

```
Binary files .Mathematica/FrontEnd/10.3_Caches/Linux-x86-64/ResourceMap.pbf and .Mathematica.bak/FrontEnd/10.3_Caches/Linux-x86-64/ResourceMap.pbf differ
Binary files .Mathematica/FrontEnd/10.3_Caches/Linux-x86-64/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/UnicodeCharacters.pbf and .Mathematica.bak/FrontEnd/10.3_Caches/Linux-x86-64/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/UnicodeCharacters.pbf differ
diff -u -r .Mathematica/FrontEnd/init.m .Mathematica.bak/FrontEnd/init.m
--- .Mathematica/FrontEnd/init.m    2018-12-11 17:02:52.000000000 +0100
+++ .Mathematica.bak/FrontEnd/init.m    2018-12-07 12:56:52.000000000 +0100
@@ -5,139 +5,52 @@
 Current3DTool->"RotateView",
 Default3DTool->"RotateView",
 VersionsLaunched->{"10.3.0"},
-NotebooksMenu->{"PiPiPartWaveTest.nb" -> {
+NotebooksMenu->{"PiPiTest.nb" -> {
+    FrontEnd`FileName[{$RootDirectory, "home", "tada", "Documents", 
+      "Wolfram Mathematica"}, "PiPiTest.nb", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"], 
+    True, False, True}, "PiPiPartWaveTest.nb" -> {
     FrontEnd`FileName[{$RootDirectory, "home", "tada", "Documents", 
       "Wolfram Mathematica"}, "PiPiPartWaveTest.nb", CharacterEncoding -> 
      "UTF-8"], True, False, True}},
-HelpViewerSettings->{"WindowMargins"->{{Automatic, 527}, {96, Automatic}},
+FindSettings->{"FindBoxes":>RowBox[{"t", "[", 
+   RowBox[{"p1", ",", "cosThet", ",", " ", "M"}], "]"}],
+"FindHistory":>{
+  RowBox[{"[", 
+    RowBox[{",", "cosThet", ",", " ", "M"}], "]"}], 
+  RowBox[{"[", 
+    RowBox[{",", "cosThet", ",", "M"}], "]"}], 
+  RowBox[{"[", 
+    RowBox[{",", "cosThet", ",", "M", ",", "sig"}], "]"}], "s"},
+"FindString"->"t[p1,cosThet, M]",
+"IgnoreCase"->True,
+"ReplaceBoxes"->"p2",
+"ReplaceHistory":>{
+  RowBox[{"[", 
+    RowBox[{"s", ",", "cosThet", ",", " ", "M", ",", "sig"}], "]"}], 
+  RowBox[{"[", 
+    RowBox[{"s", ",", "cosThet", ",", "M"}], "]"}], 
+  RowBox[{
+    RowBox[{"[", 
+      RowBox[{"s_", ",", "cosThet_", ",", "M_", ",", "F_"}], "]"}], " "}], 
+  RowBox[{"[", 
+    RowBox[{
+     "s_", ",", "cosThet_", ",", "l1_", ",", "l2_", ",", "M_", ",", "F_"}], 
+    "]"}], 
+  RowBox[{"[", 
+    RowBox[{"s", ",", "cosThet", ",", " ", "M"}], "]"}], "p1", 
+  RowBox[{"[", "p1"}], "p2"},
+"SearchType"->LiteralSearch,
+"WindowMargins"->{{14, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}},
+"Wraparound"->True},
+DebuggerSettings->{"BreakOnAllMessages"->True,
+"DebuggerEnabled"->True,
+"ShowStack"->False,
+"ToolsWindowMargins"->{{Automatic, 137}, {Automatic, 79}}},
+HelpViewerSettings->{"WindowMargins"->{{210, Automatic}, {Automatic, 97}},
 "WindowSize"->{860, 750}},
 PrivateFrontEndOptions->{"DialogSettings"->{
  "Login" -> {"RememberMe" -> True}, 
-  "WelcomeScreen" -> {"ShowRecentFilesContextMenu" -> False}, 
-  "DrawingTools" -> {
-   WindowMargins -> {{Automatic, 0}, {Automatic, 0}}, "ToolsOpener" -> True, 
-    "OperationsOpener" -> True, "FillOpener" -> True, "StrokeOpener" -> False,
-     "ArrowsOpener" -> False, "TextOpener" -> False, "PointsOpener" -> False, 
-    "RectanglesOpener" -> False, "SettingsOpener" -> False, 
-    "SwatchColors" -> {{
-       GrayLevel[0.], 
-       GrayLevel[0.09090909090909091], 
-       GrayLevel[0.18181818181818182`], 
-       GrayLevel[0.2727272727272727], 
-       GrayLevel[0.36363636363636365`], 
-       GrayLevel[0.4545454545454546], 
-       GrayLevel[0.5454545454545454], 
-       GrayLevel[0.6363636363636364], 
-       GrayLevel[0.7272727272727273], 
-       GrayLevel[0.8181818181818182], 
-       GrayLevel[0.9090909090909092], 
-       GrayLevel[1.], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91]}, {
-       Hue[0., 0.3333333333333333, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.08333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.16666666666666666`, 0.3333333333333333, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.25, 0.3333333333333333, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.4166666666666667, 0.3333333333333333, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.5833333333333334, 0.3333333333333333, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.6666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.75, 0.3333333333333333, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.8333333333333334, 0.3333333333333333, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.9166666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 1.], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91]}, {
-       Hue[0., 0.6666666666666666, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.08333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.16666666666666666`, 0.6666666666666666, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.25, 0.6666666666666666, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.4166666666666667, 0.6666666666666666, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.5, 0.6666666666666666, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.5833333333333334, 0.6666666666666666, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.6666666666666666, 0.6666666666666666, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.75, 0.6666666666666666, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.8333333333333334, 0.6666666666666666, 1.], 
-       Hue[0.9166666666666666, 0.6666666666666666, 1.], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91]}, {
-       Hue[0., 1., 1.], 
-       Hue[0.08333333333333333, 1., 1.], 
-       Hue[0.16666666666666666`, 1., 1.], 
-       Hue[0.25, 1., 1.], 
-       Hue[0.3333333333333333, 1., 1.], 
-       Hue[0.4166666666666667, 1., 1.], 
-       Hue[0.5, 1., 1.], 
-       Hue[0.5833333333333334, 1., 1.], 
-       Hue[0.6666666666666666, 1., 1.], 
-       Hue[0.75, 1., 1.], 
-       Hue[0.8333333333333334, 1., 1.], 
-       Hue[0.9166666666666666, 1., 1.], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91]}, {
-       Hue[0., 0.5, 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.08333333333333333, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.16666666666666666`, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.25, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.3333333333333333, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.4166666666666667, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.5, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.5833333333333334, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.6666666666666666, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.75, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.8333333333333334, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.9166666666666666, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91]}, {
-       Hue[0., 1., 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.08333333333333333, 1., 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.16666666666666666`, 1., 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.25, 1., 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.3333333333333333, 1., 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.4166666666666667, 1., 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.5, 1., 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.5833333333333334, 1., 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.6666666666666666, 1., 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.75, 1., 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.8333333333333334, 1., 0.6666666666666666], 
-       Hue[0.9166666666666666, 1., 0.6666666666666666], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91]}, {
-       Hue[0., 1., 0.3333333333333333], 
-       Hue[0.08333333333333333, 1., 0.3333333333333333], 
-       Hue[0.16666666666666666`, 1., 0.3333333333333333], 
-       Hue[0.25, 1., 0.3333333333333333], 
-       Hue[0.3333333333333333, 1., 0.3333333333333333], 
-       Hue[0.4166666666666667, 1., 0.3333333333333333], 
-       Hue[0.5, 1., 0.3333333333333333], 
-       Hue[0.5833333333333334, 1., 0.3333333333333333], 
-       Hue[0.6666666666666666, 1., 0.3333333333333333], 
-       Hue[0.75, 1., 0.3333333333333333], 
-       Hue[0.8333333333333334, 1., 0.3333333333333333], 
-       Hue[0.9166666666666666, 1., 0.3333333333333333], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91], 
-       GrayLevel[0.91]}}}},
+  "WelcomeScreen" -> {"ShowRecentFilesContextMenu" -> False}},
 "InterfaceSettings"->{
- "PredictiveInterface" -> {"ShowMinimized" -> False, "FirstUse" -> False}},
-"WolframAlphaSettings"->{
- "BaseURL" -> "Automatic", "Reinterpret" -> True, "Interactive" -> True, 
-  "Language" -> Automatic, "SendMathematicaSessionInfo" -> Automatic, "AppID" -> 
-  Automatic, "MathematicaFormsFormatType" -> "MostlyInputForm"}},
-NewPrimitiveStyle->{
- FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0], DrawFrontFaces -> True, FrontFaceOpacity -> 1}
+ "PredictiveInterface" -> {"ShowMinimized" -> False, "FirstUse" -> False}}}
 ]
diff -u -r .Mathematica/Paclets/Configuration/managerData_10.3.0.0.pmd2 .Mathematica.bak/Paclets/Configuration/managerData_10.3.0.0.pmd2
--- .Mathematica/Paclets/Configuration/managerData_10.3.0.0.pmd2    2018-12-10 17:41:10.000000000 +0100
+++ .Mathematica.bak/Paclets/Configuration/managerData_10.3.0.0.pmd2    2018-12-10 17:40:23.000000000 +0100
@@ -1,9 +1,9 @@
 {"ManagerDataVersion" -> 2, "AllowInternet" -> True, 
  "LastUpdatedSite" -> "http://pacletserver.wolfram.com", 
- "LastUpdatedSiteDate" -> {2018, 12, 10, 17, 41, 
-   10.329358`7.766648316110626}, "LastUsedSite" -> Null, 
+ "LastUpdatedSiteDate" -> {2018, 12, 10, 17, 40, 
+   23.092637`8.116048511696313}, "LastUsedSite" -> Null, 
  "LastUsedSiteDate" -> Null, "LastWolframAutoUpdate" -> 
-  {2018, 12, 10, 17, 41, 6.451718`7.562250363952631}, 
+  {2018, 12, 3, 12, 55, 39.47527`8.348900087668001}, 
  "NumPacletsDownloaded" -> 0, "IsDataAutoUpdate" -> True, 
  "IsDocAutoUpdate" -> True, "UseProxy" -> Automatic, "HTTPProxyHost" -> Null, 
  "HTTPProxyPort" -> 0, "HTTPSProxyHost" -> Null, "HTTPSProxyPort" -> 0, 
diff -u -r .Mathematica/Paclets/Configuration/pacletSiteData_10.pmd2 .Mathematica.bak/Paclets/Configuration/pacletSiteData_10.pmd2
--- .Mathematica/Paclets/Configuration/pacletSiteData_10.pmd2   2018-12-10 17:41:10.000000000 +0100
+++ .Mathematica.bak/Paclets/Configuration/pacletSiteData_10.pmd2   2018-12-10 17:40:23.000000000 +0100
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 0
 {{"http://pacletserver.wolfram.com", "Wolfram Research Paclet Server", False, 
-  {2018, 12, 10, 17, 41, 8.809076`7.697505343841002}, 
-  {2018, 12, 10, 17, 41, 9.809532`7.744223274955068}, 
+  {2018, 12, 10, 17, 40, 21.185901`8.078621921960671}, 
+  {2018, 12, 10, 17, 40, 22.572206`8.106148988263284}, 
   {Paclet["Name" -> "Alexa", "Version" -> "1.0.0", 
     "MathematicaVersion" -> "10+", "Description" -> "Easily create Alexa \
 skills for the Amazon Echo and other devices that support Alexa Voice \
Only in .Mathematica.bak/Paclets/Temporary: QuantityUnits-1.2.1.19262308.paclet
Only in .Mathematica.bak/SystemFiles/FrontEnd: SystemResources
Only in .Mathematica.bak: term.history
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I do not believe that `LinkConnect` could be related to communication with the license server. There are countless ways to cause things like this by changing the contents of `~/.Mathematica`.  Did you check if she had a startup script? Any auto-load packages?  Any special configuration?  Does she use Mathematica through the terminal or graphically?

Comment: One possible explanation is that she has Mathematica automatically start subkernels on startup. This is in Preferences -> Parallel -> General Preferences.  If there are not enough licenses, some of the subkernels may fail to start. If you're the sysadmin, you might want to ask her to stop doing this as it is using (sub)kernel licenses that other people may actually need. Check how many you have with `$MaxLicenseSubprocesses`

Comment: @Szabolcs: The value of `$MaxLicenseSubprocesses` is infinity, so that cannot be the issue.

Comment: It's really not possible to say more without knowing what's in her `~/.Mathematica`. By changing that directory, the system can in principle be reprogrammed to be whatever you want it to be ...

Comment: You can debug it like this: Did she ever change anything in that directory, did she ever install any packages? If no, then it's likely either caused by the FrontEnd or the Paclets directory. Try removing each (while keeping a backup of `~/.Mathematica`) to isolate the problem. If it's FrontEnd, it may be a setting she changed. If it's Paclets, it may be Wolfram's fault.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I have added the directory structure and a diff to a freshly created directory to the question. Isolating the directory is something that we can try.

Answer (score 0):

I had have that problems twice on Ubuntu and fixed it easy (in my pc) the problem was Graphics driver

If I use Intel@graphics... I get Mathematica  working form terminal with

~$ mathematica -mesa

Finally, problem is fixed if I use Nvidia graphics card with propietary drivers.